# Passing the values of the DisplayFor to the model binder

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following view , which mainly view a list of items as a displayfor:-

```
        @foreach (var item in Model.Resources) {
            <tr>
                 <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SystemInfo.MODEL)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RESOURCENAME)
                </td>
                <td>

                     @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem  => item.ResourceLocation.SiteDefinition.AccountDefinition.SDOrganization.NAME)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ResourceLocation.SiteDefinition.SDOrganization.NAME)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ComponentDefinition.COMPONENTNAME)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ResourceState.STATEDESC)
                </td>
                 <td id = "@item.RESOURCEID">

        @using (Ajax.BeginForm("CreateOn","VirtualMachine", new AjaxOptions {
         InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
         UpdateTargetId = item.RESOURCEID.ToString() ,
         LoadingElementId = "progress",
         HttpMethod = "POST"})){
 <span class="f">Hypervisor Server</span>

             @Html.DropDownListFor(model =>model.VirtualMachine.ServerID, ((IEnumerable<t.Models.Server>)ViewBag.Servers).Select(option => new SelectListItem {
                Text = (option == null ? "None" : option.Technology.Tag), 
                Value = option.ServerID.ToString(),
                Selected = (Model != null) && (Model.VirtualMachine != null) && (option.ServerID == Model.VirtualMachine.ServerID)
            }), "Choose...")
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model =>model.VirtualMachine.ServerID)
    @Html.Hidden("IT360id", item.RESOURCEID)
            @Html.Hidden("CustomerName",item.ResourceLocation.SiteDefinition.AccountDefinition.SDOrganization.NAME)
            @Html.Hidden("SiteName",item.ResourceLocation.SiteDefinition.SDOrganization.NAME)
            @Html.Hidden("ResourceName",item.RESOURCENAME)
         <input type="submit" value="Add To" class="btn btn-primary"/>
        }
```

But the user can read the data and chose to create the item on our database, using the ajax.beginform. But to do so I need to pass some values of the DisplayFor to the model binder. Currently I have added all the needed data as a hiddenfields, and then I will pass these values to my action method as follow:-

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult CreateOn(VirtualMachineOnIT360Only vm, long IT360id, string CustomerName, string SiteName, string ResourceName)
        {
```

I found that my approach is not very reliable and I am trying to figure out a more reliable solution. So can anyone advice please?
Thanks

Comment: It's not really a good idea to create a form for each element of your loop.  Is it really intended?

Comment: why It is not a good idea ?

Comment: Nevermind you are right, using multiple form isn't bad. And I didn't understand what you were trying to do at first, so I deleted my answer.  The way I see it, there is not a lot of way to do it. You can still used the hidden field, or sending only the Id of the selected dropdownlist,and the id of the selected Resource. And load the rest of the data server side. But in your case I think hiddenfield are better if the data don't need to be secured.

Answer (score 1):

To post DisplayFor back, I prefer to use hiddenfor instead of hidden like this:

```
            @Html.HiddenFor(item => item.RESOURCENAME);
```

Comment: Hi John John, no I believe there isn't. I believe that this is the only/best way. Someone may correct me though, hopefully and I will follow suite. I'd still use the HiddenFor though, as you can pull data back from ViewModel without using a string.